# The SUM of an aggregate COUNT function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a query to calculate the percentage sales of the overall policies in my database. 
The policies are split under two separate headings

- UL
- NL

The code i want should display

- product name
- number of policies sold
- policies sold per product as a percentage of the overall number of policies sold.

I have made a few attempts at scripting this code (please see below) but cannot get them to run correctly.

**Syntax 1:**

```
SELECT b.PRODUCT_NAME, b.POLICIES_SOLD, 100.00*(b.POLICIES_SOLD/SUM(b.POLICIES_SOLD)) AS'PERC_SALES'
FROM
(
SELECT a.PRODUCT_NAME, COUNT(a.PRODUCT_NAME) AS 
'POLICIES_SOLD'
    FROM 
    (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME FROM [ATLANTIS\jjudge].
[ALL_POLICIES_201706_NL]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT PRODUCT_NAME FROM [ATLANTIS\jjudge].
[ALL_POLICIES_201706_UL])a GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME)b ;
```

**Syntax 2:**

```
SELECT a.PRODUCT_NAME, a.[POLICIES SOLD], 100.00*(a.[POLICIES SOLD]/SUM(a.[POLICIES SOLD])) 
FROM 
    (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, COUNT(*) AS 'POLICIES SOLD'FROM 
[ATLANTIS\jjudge].[ALL_POLICIES_201706_NL] GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, COUNT(*) AS 'POLICIES SOLD' FROM 
[ATLANTIS\jjudge].[ALL_POLICIES_201706_UL] GROUP BY  
PRODUCT_NAME)a ;
```

**Syntax 3:**

```
SELECT b.PRODUCT_NAME, COUNT(b.PRODUCT_NAME) AS 
'POLICIES_SOLD', 100.00*
(COUNT(b.PRODUCT_NAME)/SUM(SELECT(PRODUCT_NAME)) 
    FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'POLICY_COUNT' FROM [ATLANTIS\jjudge].[ALL_POLICIES_201706_NL]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'POLICY_COUNT' FROM [ATLANTIS\jjudge].[ALL_POLICIES_201706_UL])a)) AS 'PERC_SALES'
    FROM 
    (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME FROM [ATLANTIS\jjudge].
[ALL_POLICIES_201706_NL]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT PRODUCT_NAME FROM [ATLANTIS\jjudge].
[ALL_POLICIES_201706_UL])b GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a Window Function. Modify your Syntax 1 first line as:

```
SELECT 
    b.PRODUCT_NAME, 
    b.POLICIES_SOLD, 
    100.00*b.POLICIES_SOLD/SUM(b.POLICIES_SOLD) OVER () AS 'PERC_SALES'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a single aggregation query with window functions:

```
SELECT p.PRODUCT_NAME, COUNT(*) AS POLICIES_SOLD,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as PERC_SALES
FROM ((SELECT PRODUCT_NAME
       FROM [ATLANTIS\jjudge].[ALL_POLICIES_201706_NL]
      ) UNION ALL 
      (SELECT PRODUCT_NAME
       FROM [ATLANTIS\jjudge].[ALL_POLICIES_201706_UL]
      )
     ) p
GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME;
```